# Can `hmset` guarantee all the fields operate sucessfully at the same time?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Redis cluster with multiple partition, the key is allocated on the specified partition. Can `hmset` guarantee all the fields operate sucessfully at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, hset/hmset commands are atomically. You will get all success response or non.